# Download SQL data in xlsx format with Django

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas

I have to write a function which on input has a name of a table and conditionals/filters for that query, on output it returns a link which should be automatically be download by the client (browser).

How to implement this task using python/django?

E.g. I've written a small piece of code, but I'm not sure that it works correctly and there is no implementation of query conditionals parsing (I don't know how to implement it):

direct_db.py:

```
from django.db import connection

class DirectSQL:
    def __init__(self,in_sql):
        self.sql=in_sql
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute(in_sql)
    def getDescription(self):
        columns = [desc[0] for desc in self.cursor.description]
        return columns
    def getResult(self):
        row = self.cursor.fetchall()
        return row
    def getResultAsDict(self):
        desc = self.cursor.description
        return [dict(zip([col[0].lower() for col in desc], row)) for row in self.cursor.fetchall()]
```

excel.py:

```
from ecc.direct_db import DirectSQL
import pandas as ps

class Excel:
    def __init__(self, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name
    def convert(in_args):
        q = DirectSQL("select * from self.table_name" ) # where... order by... like...
        columns = [desc[0] for desc in q.getDescription()]
        data = q.getResults()
        df = ps.DataFrame(list(data), columns)
        writer = ps.ExcelWriter('converted.xlsx')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='converted')
        writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked in something like this before, I used `xlsxwriter`, you can check its [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html) to find out how to create a xlsx and how set data into it. Then you should need some view:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse


class CreateReport(View):

    def get_data(self):
        # Query your data here, probably using self.request to get query string
        ...
        return data

    def generate_report(self):
        # Here you will create xlsx doc and populate with data according to docs linked before
        ...
        return workbook

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        document = self.generate_report()
        _file = open(document.filename, 'r')

        response(HttpResponse(_file, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % document.filename.split('/')[-1]  # Here will return a full path, that's why probably you will need a split to get only the filename
        add_never_cache_headers(response=response)  # To avoid download the same file with out of date data.
        return response
```

Then you will need an `url`

```
from myapp.views import CreateReport
url(r'^create_report/(?P<some_param_if_needed>[-\w]+)',
                       CreateReport.as_view(),
                       name='create_report'),
```

and finally in template

```
<a href="{% url 'create_report' report_name %}">Download Report</a>
```

**EDIT**

Here's a more complete example for `get_data()` method.

```
get_data(self):
    # Let's supose you have a `MyElements` model
    elements = MyElements.objects.all()

    # And let's supose you want to filter data with some GET parameter
    filter = self.request.GET.get('filter_name', None)

    if filter is not None:
        elements = elements.filter(filter_field=filter)

    return elements
```

Comment: I need also convert it from sql -> xlsx, but I don't know how to universalize it for different queries with where and like filters.

Comment: Just query the data and interate over it.

Comment: Using what? QuerySet? I just need a simple example with like, where and order by in several queries.

Comment: I'm doing this way: http://paste.org.ru/?wp6r36 How to universialize the Model as an argument? Because I'm doing a "Convert&Download" button for 136 tables which will be displayed in ExtJS and each of them has it's own sorting and filtering.

Comment: Why don't you use Django ORM?